# Angular determine route by api call

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I want to be able to lazy load components based on a api call

Ideal would be to have a api call before the routes is set

I could use a routing component and send all routes there, and load all components as children, but then I would loose the ability to lazy load the components...

I've also tied with to use guards, but if I understand it right, I can't use a guard on a wild-card route

I'm using Angular v13.2 with Universal v13.0.2

**EDIT**

I'm sorry, for the verry bad question, when I typed it, I though it was clear, but now I see how terrible it really was

I have a normal routing module looking like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { PropertyComponent } from './property/property.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then((m) => m.HomeModule),
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: PropertyComponent,
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./property/property.routing.module').then(
    (m) => m.PropertyRoutingModule
      ),
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      initialNavigation: 'enabled',
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

The problem is that my routes looks like this:

/location

**OR:**

/property

**OR:**

/location/property

So I can't use the normal "path" when setting routes like :

```
  {
     path: 'property',
     component: PropertyComponent,
     loadChildren: () =>
       import('./property/property.routing.module').then(
    (m) => m.PropertyRoutingModule
       ),
   },
   {
     path: 'location',
     component: LocationComponent,
     loadChildren: () =>
       import('./property/property.routing.module').then(
         (m) => m.PropertyRoutingModule
  ),
},
```

My hope is to get something like this:

`let componentType = http.get<number>('url')`

(returns type og component)

And then set my route after that somehow... :)

As I typed in my original question, it's easy to accomplish this within a component - subcomponent, but I would like to do it in the routing so I can keep the lazy loading

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what exactly you're trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Your question is fairly unclear. Please share a minimal example of your application, and clarify what exactly you are trying to do.